# How to perform a wildcard query in Manticore Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, manticore-search

I am tired of Elasticsearch's appetite and am searching for an alternative. Then, I found Manticore: https://manticoresearch.com/

Everything seems fine, but wildcard queries. In ES I use a lot of wildcard queries, like '*word', '*word*' and 'word*'.
Manticore does support MySQL protocol, but does not support LIKE queries, so I couldn't find any way to perform this type of queries. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Manticore Search` you can perform wildcard queries using the `MATCH()` with the `IN` and `ANY`operators.

Here is an approach of how you can achieve:

Like how you use `%`in for example MSSQL, you can use `*` operator to perform `LIKE` operations.

If the value contains `word`:

```
SELECT * FROM <index> WHERE MATCH('@<field> *word*');
```

If the value ends with `word`

```
SELECT * FROM <index> WHERE MATCH('@<field> *word');
```

If the value starts with `word`

```
SELECT * FROM <index> WHERE MATCH('@<field> word*');
```

With `IN` operation

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> IN ('Airplane', 'Vehicle');
```

With `ANY` operation

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ANY(<column>) IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```